Configuring and Installing Elastic Code Search for Azure Devops 2022
I have installed the elastic search version: 7.17.5 exactly as the readme states.
When I try and access the search url from the search server via the (Edge or Chrome) URL http://localhost:9200 using the exact same credentials that I used to configure the search during install I receive the error "Could not validate credentials"
When configuring Search in Azure Devops Server 2022.1 Admin console I receive the following error:
"An error occurred. The version of Search service deployed is not compatible with Azure DevOps Server. Ensure that your remote Search server has been updated to the latest version prior to configuring Search."
Opening the logs shows the following error:
"[Error  @16:48:15.085] Elasticsearch version found: 0.0.0, supported version: 7.17.5
[Info   @16:48:15.085] Node returned: Error
[Error  @16:48:15.085] An error occurred. The version of Search service deployed is not compatible with Azure DevOps Server. Ensure that your remote Search server has been updated to the latest version prior to configuring Search.
[Info   @16:48:15.085] Completed Service Not Installed: Error"
Appreciate your help
Thanks
Chris.
Tried various user id to configure the search in the admin console, none work
Was expecting the search configuration wizard to return no errors and allow the configuration to complete successfully
